# Reputation System for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, merit-gem

I'm on **Rails 4**, and searching a `Reputation System Gem` similar to Stack Overflow's System.

The Popular's seems to be **[Merit](https://github.com/tute/merit)** and Twitter's **[Active Reputation System](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system)**.

But i don't know which to choose, it seems that *Twitter's Active Reputation System has a larger community* (as i'm fairly new to rails), this would help me a lot. But i cant be wrong too.

I also find The Twitter **[Active Reputation System for Rails 4](https://github.com/NARKOZ/activerecord-reputation-system/tree/rails4)** but from another User

As i scooped through the 2 Gem's i did not quite get which is more similar to Stack Overflow's Reputation System.

If someone could enlighten me on these 2 Gem's on which to user for the purpose i need them, i would be very thankful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From documentation of **Active Reputation System**:

> Let's say we want to keep track of user karma in Q&A site where user
>   karma is sum of questioning skill and answering skill. Questioning
>   skill is sum of votes for user's questions and Answering skill is sum
>   of average rating of user's answers.

looks to me like it describes exactly your case. I would go with this and probably would use merit gem too to have badges at some point for user.

Comment: Hey Magnum, thanks for answering. As i understood from looking at the gem, it doesn't have reputation right ? It's just for votes. I'm looking for a solution where User's get awarded for answering and etc.

Comment: I Updated my Question with a link to a Rails4:branch for Active Rep System. Can you give it a look? In my case i need Votes AND Reputation AND Badges :) Just like Stackoverflow. What do you recommend ?

Comment: updated answer, I would use both as merit gem has the functionality for badges. using both can't do no harm.

Comment: Cool Thanks, Should i user the Branch:Rails4 from that other Guy or should i go with the official Twitter branch. (PS I'm on Rails 4)

Comment: you can use the one you found for rails 4 and later switch to the official one if that would be needed.

Comment: About merit. you can avoid using merit if you create your own badge model and assign it to user when user acheive for example a certain number of karma or some other things that he might do.. like after adding 10 comments he will get the "Commenter" badge. Try to build badge functionality without Merit first.

Answer (score 4):

Merit keeps track of [user's karma in the form of points](https://github.com/tute/merit#defining-point-rules), and also [badges à la StackOverflow](https://github.com/tute/merit#badges). It also has a concept of rankings, which would be useful for example for "starred-restaurant".

It is similar to SO, and I can't help with the comparison cause I didn't yet use Twitter's Active Reputation System.